# Python curve fit optimize using relative deviation instead of absolute deviation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am fitting curve using the [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). From what I notice, the curve fitting is performed by minimizing the sum of the squared residuals of `f(xdata, *popt) - ydata`, whereas I want to minimize the squared residuals of relative error: `(f(xdata, *popt) - ydata)/ydata` since my `ydata` order of magnitude varies a lot. How to optimize using the relative deviation? I do not need to necessarily use `curve_fit` function. Any python function to achieve this is fine.

PS: I am aware of another approach of converting the `ydata` into logspace and fitting the resulting data. But I do not want to do this approach.

Comment: @jezrael I feel this is still more like a python-specific programming question and probably wider reach here.

Comment: OK, then unfortunately I have no idea how should be solved it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error weighting with the inverse `y` data is equivalent to a transformation into log-space. This is for the following reason: In a standard least square fit the data `y` deviates from the "true" function value `yt` by the error `sa`. The least-square fit minimizes the sum of `y - yt = sa` over all data. When going to log-space this reads `log(y) - log(yt) = log( yt + sa) - log( yt ) = log( 1 + sa / yt ) = log( y / yt )` using the standard rules for logarithms.

This gives, hence, the relative error as also pointed out by JJacquelin .

BTW, as the least square makes the square, of course, this is also `( log( y ) - log( yt ) )**2 = ( -log( y ) + log( yt ) )**2 = log( yt / y )**2`

Comment: Couple of things: You can also add the inverse weights as alternative option for log-space conversion. Please balance the parentheses in the last line.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that it is related to the previous question [scipy curve_fit coefficient does not align with expected value (physics relevant?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66839107/scipy-curve-fit-coefficient-does-not-align-with-expected-value-physics-relevant)

Instead of importing ydata, import a new numerical file made of log(ydata).

And replace the function f(xdata) by a new function log(f(xdata)).

This is equvalent to change the criteria of fitting from LMSE to LMSRE.

Comment: Converting the data to log is not an equivalent of doing LMSRE. It is basically bringing down the data range closer. As I told in the question, I’m not looking for converting data to log space. I really wonder if this relative deviation approach is already in-built into these functions.

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: What you suggested would definitely improve the fit. But what I asked is different.

Comment: @SKPS Well, this is what log-space does, relative error. If you have at point `x` the theoretical value of `a` and measured `a + sa`,  the difference for the least squares is `( a + sa ) - a = sa`. In log-space you have `log(a + sa) - log( a ) = log( 1 + sa/a )`. If you do not like this, you may use `least_squares` instead and weight the data with the inverse theoretical value as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66689232/803359)

Comment: @mikuszefski : You are right. Weighting with 1/y is also an equivalent method. Pertinent comment (+1).

Comment: @mikuszefski Thanks a lot for taking time and explaining things. If you can post this as answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @JJacquelin Sorry I did not see this connection earlier. Now it looks clear.